# Why does the hospital in Another have no fourth floor?

Tags: culture, another

In the hospital where Sakakibara was having his checkups and where Sanae worked, the elevator had no 4th floor.

Now, I know in Japanese culture the numbers 4 (四 *shi*) and 7 (七 *shichi*) have "shi" in them which is "death" (死 *shi*) and the Japanese are very superstitious, so they have alternate names for 4 and 7 (*yon* and *nana*).

So I'm wondering, is it just in *Another*, where the theme is death, that the 4th floor (and possibly the 7th floor, never really noticed) is missing, or is it a cultural thing in Japan to label the 4th floor as the 5th floor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true for many East Asian cultures, because, as you pointed out, 4 sounds like "Death". You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraphobia). It's the same as the idea that many western hotels skip the 13th floor and instead label it the 14th floor because 13 is a superstitious number.

Japanese hotels sometimes also skip the 13th floor.

Answer (score 4):

[@kuwaly's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5698/1908) is essentially correct.

I'd just like to add that I've never heard of the 7th floor being excluded from a building. The major numerical superstitions in Japanese (and probably Chinese, etc.) surround the numbers 4 (四 *yon* or *shi*) and 9 (九 *ku* or *kyuu*), since they sound like "death" (死, *shi*) and "suffering" (苦 *ku*). To the best of my knowledge, there are no similar superstitions surrounding the number 7 (despite the fact that, as you correctly point out, 7 can be read *shichi*).

Also, just to make this clear - the presence of "alternate" readings like *yon* and *nana* (for 4 and 7 respectively) isn't purely because of superstition. Rather, it's because there are two parallel schemes for counting in Japanese, one of which uses native Japanese words (*hito*, *futa*, *mi*, *yo*, *itsu*, ...), and one of which uses Chinese imports (*itsu* / *ichi*, *ni* / *ji*, *san*, *shi*, *go*, ...). This is vaguely similar to how English has native words (one, two, three, four, five...) and Greek/Latin imports (mono / uni, di / bi, tri, tetra / quad, pent / quint, ...). If you're interested in learning more, consider asking a question on [**Japanese.SE**](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)