# Does the name Shiki have some sort of relevance to Death?

Tags: the-garden-of-sinners, tsukihime

In Kara no Kyoukai and the Tsukihime games, the characters who can see death have the first name Shiki:

- Ryougi Shiki: **Kara no Kyoukai** - Obtained from being overly exposed to Akasha while in a Comma dying
- Tohno Shiki: **Tsukihime** - Obtained from almost dying when attacked by SHIKI
- Tohno SHIKI: **Tsukihime** - Obtained from being with Roa (unsure if Roa has to be dominant as he was in Near Side Routes, SHIKI is dominant in Far Side Routes)
- Nanaya Shiki: **Melty Blood** - Derived from Tohno Shiki as Nanaya is an aspect of Tohno's personality and brought into the world though TATARI's powers (used by White Len)

I am wondering if the name Shiki has relevance to death or being able to see death. (From my understanding, neither Roa or Tohno SHIKI have the Mystic Eyes of Death Perception, just the understanding of it through Roa's many reincarnations.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably related to the fact that "shi" is death in Japanese. The kanji for death is "死", however, which does not appear in any of the names of characters you listed. The word would still be associated with death, (as shown by the [tetraphobia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5694/why-does-the-hospital-in-another-have-no-fourth-floor) that appears throughout Japan).

Those characters are all from Type-Moon series, also, so the connection may also come from that fact. Tsukihime and Melty Blood are directly related, existing in the same world, while Kara no Kyoukai is not.

Comment: Technically Melty Blood is only implied to be related to Tsukihime because it follows the cut Satsuki Yumizuka Route and Kagetsu Tohya which introduces Len and Nanaya, until we get the Tsukihime remake and see what happens to Satsuki Yumizuka all we can say is that "some event occurred which allowed Satsuki Yumizuka to become a vampire and live" like with another Type-Moon works which occurs "in a world where Tsukihime never happened"