# Why is 44 a bad number?

Tags: gundam-build-fighters

In episode 13 of Gundam Build Fighters, the number 44 comes up as a bad number.
Why is 44 considered a bad number?

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5694/why-does-the-hospital-in-another-have-no-fourth-floor, probably the same how Japanese numbers are structured

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link in the comment was correct.

Number four in Japan is considered bad luck.
This is because both four and death are pronounced the same way - *shi*. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraphobia#In_Japan))

Comment: This is a Chinese heritage, as can be read in the article you cited.

Answer (score 1):

In both Chinese and Japanese language, the pronunciation of "death" and the number "four" are so close:

- Mandarin: si4 (four) and si3 (death)
- Cantonese: si2 or sei2 (both "death" or "four")
- Japanese: shi (both "four" and "death")